# $L_{1,1}$-norm and orthonormal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, orthogonality, orthonormal, orthogonal-matrices

Given any point $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and two matrices whose columns are orthonormal $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times j}$, $Y \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times (n - j)}$, such that $Y$ spans the orthogonal compliment of $X$.

Is it true that 
$$
\left| \left|\  pW \ \right| \right|_{1,1} \approx \left| \left|\  pX \ \right| \right|_{1,1} + \left| \left|\  pY \ \right| \right|_{1,1}?
$$
where $W = [X | Y]$ is the concatenation of $X$ and $Y$ ($W \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$).

And if it's true, how can we prove it? (It's known that the above is actually an equality when $L_{1,1}$ norm is replaced by the squared frobenius).

For more reference, do see the definition of $L_{1,1}$ [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#L2,1_and_Lp,q_norms).

I am asking this since if we compute it in MATLAB, then its not even equal (however for me I don't see why it wouldn't be equal)

Thanks in advance.